# How to do the rescaling here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following equations model the motion of a rigid body about its centre of mass, where $\vec{\Omega}$ is the angular velocity vector in the body and $I_1,I_2,I_3$ are the principal moments of inertia:
$$
\begin{align*}
I_1\dot{\Omega}_1&=(I_2-I_3)\Omega_2\Omega_3\\
I_2\dot{\Omega}_2&=(I_3-I_1)\Omega_3\Omega_1\\
I_3\dot{\Omega}_3&=(I_1-I_2)\Omega_1\Omega_2.
\end{align*}
$$

Can this be rescaled to the system
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{u}_1&=u_2u_3\\
\dot{u}_2&=u_3u_1\\
\dot{u}_3&=u_1u_2?
\end{align*}
$$

Is this straightforward (and am I just too stupid)?

---

My first idea was to rescale time by $t=\lambda\tau$ but this seems not to work.

Comment: Are you trying to non-dimensionalize the system so as to make it more stable under numerical calculations?

Comment: Actually, I do not know what is the purpose. I just read in a book that it is easier to work with the second system of equations and I would like to know how to get there.

Comment: I think re-scaling time might be a productive idea, but you need to re-scale differently for each function. Try $\Omega_1(t)=u_1(\lambda_1 t), \Omega_2(t)=u_2(\lambda_2 t),$ and $\Omega_3(t)=u_3(\lambda_3 t).$ Also, you might need the $\lambda_i$'s to be functions of time.

Comment: Assuming that the $I_k$ are sorted in descending order, you would need to introduce a minus sign in the second equation, $\dot u_2=-u_1u_3$. Then normalization with $Ω_k(t)=c_ku_k(t)$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $Ω_1(t)=c_2c_3u_1(t)$, etc., then you get
$$
I_1=(I_2-I_3)c_1^2\\
I_2=(I_3-I_1)c_2^2\\
I_3=(I_1-I_2)c_3^2\\
$$
Now the best one can do is to set
$$
c_1=\sqrt{\frac{I_1}{|I_2-I_3|}}
$$
etc., so that the reduced equations retain the sign of the difference factor on the right.

This obviously becomes singular when the principal moments are close together or identical.